# emacs custom C++ compilation support

Tags: emacs, makefile

I use a wrapper around make to compile C++ code within a project.

For example, the project Foo is laid out as follows:

```
Foo/ 
Foo/src/...
Foo/lib_1/..
Foo/lib_2/...
etc
```

where lib_1, lib_2 are library dependencies of Foo. The src directory has a single
make file which I run on the command line.

Is there a way to teach emacs to always run that file when I do M-x compile? And understand how
to jump to an error in some other file buffer (or open a new buffer for a file) depending on
what the error is on running make (g++) ?

Edit: I guess what I am asking for is project support and support within the project to run a specific custom make file, where errors point to files within the project that emacs can navigate to.

Comment: You mean M-x compile? I don't have an M-x make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the variable `compile-command`. This is what M-x compile defaults to, so you can set it to run the makefile you want. E.g.

```
cd /your/root/dir ; make
```

Also see the command `recompile` if you don't want to always press enter. It's also worth it to bind it to some key.